# ArgoCD ingress is not reachable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, argocd

I’m trying to set up `argocd` in EKS cluster using helm. I want to use ALB as a load balancer.  The UI is reachable through `http://node_ip:8080`, but not through the ALB or the LB that was created.

Here is my configuration:

```
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: IP
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: "${cert}"
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-policy: ELBSecurityPolicy-FS-1-2-Res-2020-10
```

Here is the ingress that was created:

```
kubectl get ing -n argocd

NAME            CLASS    HOSTS                         ADDRESS                                                          PORTS   AGE
argocd-server   <none>   eks-test-alb-argocd.abc.com   internal-k8s-argocd-argocdse-111.222.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80      9h
```

Here is what i get when trying to use the DNS or the LB address:

```
curl internal-k8s-argocd-argocdse-111-222.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: something weird w/ your `backend-protocol`, `backend-protocol-version`, and/or `listen-ports` - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-464-issues

Comment: you should also use https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl instead of curl if you are hitting a grpc backend

Comment: I've edited the configuration. Now i get 502 error. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: I feel like there is more to your helm vals above; you should be running your service as a `LoadBalancer` and I feel like you may be in `ClusterIp` mode. we are also running https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller, but in our use case, we are using service annotation instead of ingress annotations

Comment: also..im confused, you keep using `curl` instead of `grpcurl`...and i see your value `ingressGrpc.enabled = true`

Comment: I don't use GRPC. I forgot to delete the `ingressGrpc` from my question. I've updated the configuration in my question.

Comment: just making sure, is `ingress` a key within the `server` key? just looking over the docs - https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm/tree/main/charts/argo-cd. are there any logs to the `argocd_server` pod that seem helpful? is there anything from your `ingress-nginx` pods or ingress controller that can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have found the issue, and it was much simple than i thought.

Since the pods are listening to port 80, all I had to do is to change the `backend-protocol` to `HTTP`. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

from your below, it looks like your ingress isn't forwarding 443 to the service

```
kubectl get ing -n argocd

NAME            CLASS    HOSTS                         ADDRESS                                                          PORTS   AGE
argocd-server   <none>   eks-test-alb-argocd.abc.com   internal-k8s-argocd-argocdse-111.222.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80      9h
```

can you set `server.ingress.https` to be true in your helm value?

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a second service for the `argocd-server`? According to the docs:

> This is necessary because we need to tell the ALB to send the GRPC traffic to a different target group then the UI traffic, since the backend protocol is HTTP2 instead of HTTP1.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: HTTP2 #This tells AWS to send traffic from the ALB using HTTP2. Can use GRPC as well if you want to leverage GRPC specific features
  labels:
    app: argogrpc
  name: argogrpc
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "443"
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

The other thing that you're missing in your ingress definition is the following conditional in your annotations:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.argogrpc: |
        [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "Content-Type", "values":["application/grpc"]}}]
```

This is to route all application/grpc traffic to the HTTP2 backend previously created.

Reference:

1. https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/#aws-application-load-balancers-albs-and-classic-elb-http-mode